# Mejorar rendimiento al ordenar array

Tags: javascript, estructuras-de-datos, optimización

He creado una función por mi cuenta para ordenar arrays de forma descendiente y quisiera modificarlo para tener **un rendimiento cercano en comparación con la función nativa** de Javascript, aqui está:

```js
function essorted(...arr) {
  var o = [],
    max = arr.length,
    f = 0;
  for (; f < max; f++) {
    var flag = 0,
      a = arr[f];
    while (a > o[o.length - 1 - flag] && flag > -1) {
      flag += 1;
    }
    /* Si el elemento actual es mayor que el elemento el cual se está recorriendo en el array ordenado "o", este sumará +1 a flag para así seguir buscando y parará cuando sea menor o flag sea = 0 , con esto
puedo encontrar la ubicación de donde debe ir el número, según:

o.length - flag 

*/

    o.splice(o.length - flag, 0, a);
  }
  return o;
}
var a = [4, 9, 3, 0, 77, 1, 108, 5, 6, 2, 1000];
console.log(essorted.apply(null, a));
```

Adicionalmente quisiera saber:

- ¿Por qué el bajo rendimiento?
- ¿Cuáles son los errores o antipatrones de mi código?

Comment: Igual este tipo de cuestiones no encajan aquí tan bien como pudieran encajar en [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). No tengo claro que la pregunta encaje apropiadamente con el sitio

Answer (score 0):

No intenta ser una respuesta, pero realizando algunas pruebas para ordenar números de forma descendente, entre tu código y a la función nativa `.sort()`, es evidente lo que indicas.

En estas demostraciones estoy utilizando `setTimeout()` para ejecutar las comparaciones para evitar la acumulación de esfuerzo del navegador al ejecutar código de manera simultánea, y así tener mediciones más precisas.

**Comparación entre función desarrollada y función Nativa `sort()`:**

```js
function essorted(...arr) {
  var o = [],
    max = arr.length,
    f = 0;
  for (; f < max; f++) {
    var flag = 0,
      a = arr[f];
    while (a > o[o.length - 1 - flag] && flag > -1) {
      flag += 1;
    }
    /* Si el elemento actual es mayor que el elemento el cual se está recorriendo en el array ordenado "o", este sumará +1 a flag para así seguir buscando y parará cuando sea menor o flag sea = 0 , con esto
puedo encontrar la ubicación de donde debe ir el número, según:

o.length - flag 

*/

    o.splice(o.length - flag, 0, a);
  }
  return o;
}
setTimeout(function() {
  console.time("Custom sort");
  var a = [4, 9, 3, 0, 77, 1, 108, 5, 6, 2, 1000];
  console.log(essorted.apply(null, a));
  console.timeEnd("Custom sort");


  setTimeout(function() {
    console.time("Native sort");
    var b = [4, 9, 3, 0, 77, 1, 108, 5, 6, 2, 1000];
    console.log(b.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b - a;
    }));
    console.timeEnd("Native sort");
  }, 2000);
}, 1000);
```

Google Chrome: Versión 61.0.3163.100 (Build oficial) (64 bits)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que encuentro en tu código es que estás:

1. Creando e inicializando la variable `flag` dentro de un bucle. *Mejor creas la variable fuera del bucle y sólo lo inicializas en el bucle.*
2. Estás calculando la cantidad de elementos de un array en un bucle. *Mejor creas un variable `len` fuera del bucle y actualizas su valor en el bucle.*
3. `flag > -1` siempre se cumplirá esa condición. *Mejor lo retiramos.*

**Comparación final entre versión desarrollada y versión mejorada:**

```js
function essorted(...arr) {
  var o = [],
    max = arr.length,
    f = 0;
  for (; f < max; f++) {
    var flag = 0,
      a = arr[f];
    while (a > o[o.length - 1 - flag] && flag > -1) {
      flag += 1;
    }
    /* Si el elemento actual es mayor que el elemento el cual se está recorriendo en el array ordenado "o", este sumará +1 a flag para así seguir buscando y parará cuando sea menor o flag sea = 0 , con esto
puedo encontrar la ubicación de donde debe ir el número, según:

o.length - flag 

*/

    o.splice(o.length - flag, 0, a);
  }
  return o;
}

function essorted2(...arr) {
  var o = [],
    max = arr.length,
    f = 0,
    flag, len; // Se crean las variables sin valor inicial, fuera del bucle.
  for (; f < max; f++) {
    flag = 0, // Se asigna el valor de la variable flag.
      a = arr[f],
      len = o.length; // Se actualiza el valor de la variable len dentro del bucle for pero fuera del while.
    while (a > o[len - 1 - flag]) { // Se utiliza los valores de las variables len y flag. Esta parte podría mejorarse.
      flag += 1;
    }
    /* Si el elemento actual es mayor que el elemento el cual se está recorriendo en el array ordenado "o", este sumará +1 a flag para así seguir buscando y parará cuando sea menor o flag sea = 0 , con esto
puedo encontrar la ubicación de donde debe ir el número, según:

o.length - flag 

*/
    o.splice(len - flag, 0, a);
  }
  return o;
}


setTimeout(function() {
  console.time("essorted");
  var a = [4, 9, 3, 0, 77, 1, 108, 5, 6, 2, 1000];
  console.log(essorted.apply(null, a));
  console.timeEnd("essorted");

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.time("essorted2");
    var b = [4, 9, 3, 0, 77, 1, 108, 5, 6, 2, 1000];
    console.log(essorted2.apply(null, b));
    console.timeEnd("essorted2");
  }, 2000);
}, 1000);
```

Con esto puedes tener una leve mejora.

Google Chrome: Versión 61.0.3163.100 (Build oficial) (64 bits)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te recomiendo puedas consultar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation, en la que se menciona sobre la implementación de `Array.sort()`. Podrías tener información adicional sobre el algoritmo de implementación de esta función.

Como indica @frikinside, te recomiendo derivar esta pregunta a https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.